# HTML5 Video, with Javascript to change source, not loading on Safari, fine on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I am currently working on a site that has a full page video background that changes video using JavaScript at the end of each video. It works perfectly on Chrome or Firefox, however, it just won't load the videos on Safari, it stays blank. When I look at resources in inspector, all I see is

> An error occurred trying to load the resource.

[Site](http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk)

Any help would be extremely appreciated as it is driving me nuts!

EDIT -

Here is the HTML for the video:

```
<video id="homepagevid" poster="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Scallops2-Image.jpg" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" width="300" height="150">
<source src="http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Scallops.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Here's the js I use to change videos -

```
var nextVideo = ["http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Scallops.mp4","http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Meat.mp4","http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Pudding.mp4","http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Bread.mp4", "http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Tomatoes.mp4"];
var nextPoster = "http://www.kingsarmspentyrch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/black.jpg";
var currentVideo = 0;
var homepagevid = document.getElementById('homepagevid');
homepagevid.onended = function(){
    if(currentVideo === 0){
        homepagevid.src = nextVideo[1];
        currentVideo = 1;
    } else if(currentVideo === 1){
        homepagevid.src = nextVideo[2];
        currentVideo = 2;
    } else if(currentVideo === 2){
        homepagevid.src = nextVideo[3];
        currentVideo = 3;
    } else if(currentVideo === 3){
        homepagevid.src = nextVideo[4];
        currentVideo = 4;
    } else if(currentVideo === 4) {
        homepagevid.src = nextVideo[0];
        currentVideo = 0;
    }
};

homepagevid.oncanplay = function(){
        homepagevid.poster = nextPoster;
};
```

Cheers For Any Help guys, this is driving me insane.

Dave

Comment: Could you provide some code? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Wavemaster thanks for your reply, I apologise I forgot to add in the code, please see above. Many thanks, Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the canplay event callback you are 'hidding' the video putting the poster over it. If you remove the `homepagevid.poster = nextPoster;` from the canplay event callback you will watch all the videos. 
If you want you can put the `homepagevid.poster = nextPoster;` at the beginning of the ended event callback.

Comment: You absolute life saver! Thank you so much that was exactly what was wrong. Cheers, Dave.